# Can 'infinitive' be omitted in "May I ask ~?"

Tags: grammaticality

My question is about this sentence,

> May I ask your last portrait be of me?

Why 'be' here?

It should be "May I ask your last portrait to be of me?", shouldn't it?
Is 'to' just dropped? Or can 'to' be omitted?　
What about 'should'?
I could use any help.

Comment: I would just put the "that" in there.  May I ask that your last portrait be of me?

Comment: If you want an explicitly infinitive verb (rather than "subjunctive") you should include another preposition: *May I ask **for** your last portrait **to be** of me?*

Comment: You may not be aware of our sister site, SE English Language Learners. I strongly suggest that this sort of question may fit there, rather than on "a site for  linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts".

Answer (score 4):

It's the subjunctive—it's a shortening of "May I ask that your last portrait be of me."

Your correction, "May I ask your last portrait to be of me," is wrong, because you're not asking the portrait itself to do anything. You could instead ask "May I ask you to paint me for your last portrait," which would be much more natural in contemporary English than the sentence you give using the subjunctive mood.

Comment: 'May I ask the portrait of the large lady to let us poor Gryffindor students into the dorms?'

Comment: 'May I ask the portrait of the lar6e lady to let us 6oor 6ryffindor students into the dorms?' ---> She said, "Don't make others suffer for your personal hatred."  https://anagram-solver.net/%27May%20I%20ask%20the%20portrait%20of%20the%20lar6e%20lady%20to%20let%20us%206oor%206ryffindor%20students%20into%20the%20dorms%27?partial=true